# No external DNS when connected to Cisco VPN and tethered

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, vpn, dns, cisco-vpn-client

I use Cisco AnyConnect to access a VPN for our main vendor.  I use it on my desktop at the office every day.  Today I'm working from my laptop at home but due to internet slowness I tethered my laptop to my phone's LTE hotspot.  When I connect to the VPN I then lose all access to any non-vpn resources (like Google).  I switched my laptop back to the DSL network and everything was back to normal.

Is this a configuration issue or something else?

Here are the Statistics and Route Details tabs as requested:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clicking on VPN present on main UI will bring a pop up with "Statistics" tab. What does the "Connection Information" say ? Also what information does "Route Details" tab have ?

Comment: Here I am 4 months later forced to use my laptop and cell phone and I'm having the same issue.  This has to be an easy fix!

Comment: We need more information about your phone and how you create the hotspot.

Comment: Verizon Note Edge, Stock/carrier hotspot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following thread from 2014 seems to handle your case
[Can I share my Android's VPN connection over a Hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60819/can-i-share-my-androids-vpn-connection-over-a-hotspot)

It contains several suggestions that require rooting the phone,
which is not really recommended.

I refer to the one [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77594/7736) that does not require rooting :

> Unfortunately **the stock Android tethering application does not work with VPNs**.
>   This limitation is an oversight in the software and not a
>   system limitation.
>
> However there is an application called [ClockworkMod Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether&hl=en) that
>   will allow you to tether and use a VPN at the same time. In fact it
>   makes use of the standard tethering application and then fixes up the
>   routing information to make it work.
>
> This application does not require you to root your phone but you do
>   need to run software on the computer that you wish to connect to your
>   phone. Also this only works for USB tethering at the moment.
>
> There are other alternatives to ClockworkMod Tether, if you wish to
>   try them, including [PDANet+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet&hl=en).

I note that ClockworkMod Tether is a 14 day trial. You will have full unfettered usage for 14 days, after which you will only be able to download 20MB a day. You will need to  buy Tether Premium for $4.99 from the application's menu to unlock the full version.

The free edition of PdaNet+ has timed usage limit, but is otherwise the same as the full version. I have not found the paid version on Google Play,
so do not know its cost. The upgrade is probably done as in-app purchase.

I have never used both these applications and cannot vouch for them.